# NGINX location rewrite URL with or without trailing slash

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

Currently I have this location block:

```
location = /events {
    rewrite ^ https://totallydifferenturl.com;
}
```

This successfully redirects from `mywebsite/events`, but I want this block to also handle `mywebsite/events/`.

Trying `location = /events/?` didn't work out.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need the `~` operator to enable regex matching, and since you only need to match `website/events` or `website/events/` as full strings, you will need anchors `^` and `$` around the pattern:

```
location ~ ^/events/?$
         ^ ^         ^
```

The `^/events/?$` pattern matches:

- `^` - start of input
- `/events` - a literal substring `/events`
- `/?`  - one or zero `/` symbols
- `$` - end of input.

Comment: This is perfect. What would be the implication if I ignored the anchors and simply used `/events/?` Would it also match something like `website/random/events/query`?

Comment: Yes, it would match `/events` or `/events/` anywhere inside the string.